# Is there a way to differ between iOS App Store downloads by link vs downloads via search

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, mobile-application

How to record an App Store download ?
I am making a website for my app with my app link. Whenever user presses that link , they are redirected to the App Store. Now how should I find out if the app was downloaded by that link nn the website or whether it was dowloaded from somewhere else/searched on the App Store.

For example : How to find out that User A downloaded the app from the link on the website vs User B who searched the app on the App Store and downloaded it?

Comment: Store something in the cookies on the website. And at the first launch open website from the app again. Read that value from the cookies and then redirect back to the app with it.

Comment: You can know if user pressed the link on the site and correlate that to total number of downloads the store itself provides.